# "Update Your Amazon RDS SSL/TLS Certificates by February 5, 2020" Where to upload new cert

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, certificate, rds

I did not set these up initially, and,  to be frank, am a little green when it comes to AWS infrastructure.

I found, in the dashboard, where I select `rds-ca-2019` but then it warns me to download the new certificate and upload that first, so I do not experience any interruption.

My issue is that I have searched every area I can think of, and I am unable to find where I put this new certificate.  None of the connections I can find in the dashboard for the VPC, subnets, or any other endpoint appears to use a certificate.

I have googled this quite a bit and I also read the documentation that AWS links to in their emails (and within the post itself) but I just can't seem to find the answer to this.

The DB is MySQL 5.7.22 in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

If none of your applications connect to the RDS resource using a cert, then you don't need to download it to anything. You just make the change on the RDS side and all is fine.

I would still suggest doing the change off hours of a maintenance window. In case you missed something that does require the cert. If anything does break when you make the change, you can easily change the cert back to teh old one again and research.